Ancient Rome philosophy newsletter
I will be writing a weekly newsletter that explains pieces of Classical philosophy (from Ancient Rome) to make Latin literature and philosophy accessible to everyone. It is hard to truly understand an author's intent and ideas from a simple translation: that is what I aim to fix with this newsletter.
Please consider subscribing if you're interested in this sort of thing: as an enthused Latin student, I love analytical writing and the Classics and am excited to combine these two! It will start shortly after the new year.
https://odietamo1.substack.com/?r=ugu11&utm_campaign=pub-share-checklist
